# Linking several LLVM C++ modules together segfaults in lli

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I'm trying a very simple example with LLVM/clang and seem to fail.

I try the following:

1. clang++ -emit-llvm -c -x c++ -o main.bc -isystem include/ main.cc
2. clang++ -emit-llvm -c -x c++ -o test_class.bc -isystem include/ test_class.cc
3. llvm-link main.bc test_class.bc -o all.bc
4. lli all.bc

However, 4. fails (segfaults) with:

```
0  libLLVM-3.3.so  0x0000003b890f9e52 llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(_IO_FILE*) + 34
1  libLLVM-3.3.so  0x0000003b890f9cb9
2  libpthread.so.0 0x0000003b8520efa0
3  libLLVM-3.3.so  0x0000003b89982790 llvm::MachineJumpTableInfo::getEntrySize(llvm::DataLayout const&) const + 0
4  libLLVM-3.3.so  0x0000003b894bfb23
5  libLLVM-3.3.so  0x0000003b894c8dc3
6  libLLVM-3.3.so  0x0000003b8981b27f
7  libLLVM-3.3.so  0x0000003b8969d2d6 llvm::FPPassManager::runOnFunction(llvm::Function&) + 422
8  libLLVM-3.3.so  0x0000003b8969d3f6 llvm::FunctionPassManagerImpl::run(llvm::Function&) + 102
9  libLLVM-3.3.so  0x0000003b8969d4cb llvm::FunctionPassManager::run(llvm::Function&) + 91
10 libLLVM-3.3.so  0x0000003b894b3264 llvm::JIT::jitTheFunction(llvm::Function*, llvm::MutexGuard const&) + 36
11 libLLVM-3.3.so  0x0000003b894b394f llvm::JIT::runJITOnFunctionUnlocked(llvm::Function*, llvm::MutexGuard const&) + 15
12 libLLVM-3.3.so  0x0000003b894b3b7e llvm::JIT::getPointerToFunction(llvm::Function*) + 254
13 libLLVM-3.3.so  0x0000003b894c6649
14 libLLVM-3.3.so  0x0000003b894c909c
15 libLLVM-3.3.so  0x0000003b8981b27f
16 libLLVM-3.3.so  0x0000003b8969d2d6 llvm::FPPassManager::runOnFunction(llvm::Function&) + 422
17 libLLVM-3.3.so  0x0000003b8969d3f6 llvm::FunctionPassManagerImpl::run(llvm::Function&) + 102
18 libLLVM-3.3.so  0x0000003b8969d4cb llvm::FunctionPassManager::run(llvm::Function&) + 91
19 libLLVM-3.3.so  0x0000003b894b3264 llvm::JIT::jitTheFunction(llvm::Function*, llvm::MutexGuard const&) + 36
20 libLLVM-3.3.so  0x0000003b894b394f llvm::JIT::runJITOnFunctionUnlocked(llvm::Function*, llvm::MutexGuard const&) + 15
21 libLLVM-3.3.so  0x0000003b894b3b7e llvm::JIT::getPointerToFunction(llvm::Function*) + 254
22 lli             0x00000000004073cf main + 2527
23 libc.so.6       0x0000003b84621b75 __libc_start_main + 245
24 lli             0x000000000040a271
Stack dump:
0.      Program arguments: lli all.bc 
1.      Running pass 'X86 Machine Code Emitter' on function '@main'
2.      Running pass 'X86 Machine Code Emitter' on function '@_ZN10test_classC2ESs'
[1]    15327 segmentation fault (core dumped)  lli all.bc
```

Do I have a fundamental missunderstanding on how this is supposed to work? My ultimate goal is to do the compilation
part using the libclang API, but for now understanding what I do wrong here would be awesome! Thanks!

I attached the source code for the example below:

include/test_class.h:

```
#ifndef __TEST_CLASS_H__
#define __TEST_CLASS_H__

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct test_class
{
  test_class(std::string foo);
  ~test_class();

  std::string foo;
};

#endif
```

test_class.cc:

```
#include <test_class.h>

test_class::test_class(std::string foo) : foo(foo)
{
  std::cout << foo << std::endl;
}

test_class::~test_class(void)
{
}
```

main.cc:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include <test_class.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  test_class test("foo");

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `test_class` you refer to `std::string`. I *guess*, calls to related functions are marked `external` if you have a look into the IR (eg: `llvm-dis < all.bc`).

If you compile to "normal" executable code, these calls are resolved by the linker. 
Since you link manually with `llvm-link` you will have to provide IR-code for the C++ libraries, otherwise execution might fail.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but didn't fix it.

Comment: Can you confirm my theory? If so, the solution is non-trivial, because you need to manage compiling the C++ libraries (+ their dependencies) to IR code. Linking against a binary (as in a "normal" compile process) is not possible here.

Comment: Even if I remove the std::string and std::cout stuff, same thing happens. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Well, if you can provide me with the output of `llvm-dis < all.bc` (through a GIST or similar) I will have a quick look. ;)

Comment: The IR code is full of calls to std::* and if you have a look, the referenced functions are only *declare*d, but not *define*d (eg. they have no function body) -- as said above, traditionally this is resolved by the linker which replaces these call addresses by addresses of already compiled libraries. Since you try to execute with the interpreter, `lli` does not know what to do when such functions are called.
When you removed the calls to std::string and so on, did you also remove the `#include`? If not, do so, because there seems to be some static initialisation in there.

Comment: Seems I was wrong: I tried a minimal example and `lli` seems to be able to dynamically link to the libstdc++ libraries and `cout`, `string` and so on work properly. Your problem must be somewhere else...

Comment: @cpt.jazz Hi, how do you get lli link to std lib. As far as I know, it just jit compile the module and run it. If I was wrong, please let me know!